# A stange eigenproblem

Tags: complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Suppose we have a second-order operator $\hat{L}$. Do anybody know of the following problem:
$$\hat{L}f=\lambda\bar{f} $$
It is very similar to the normal eigenproblem but with a particular complex conjugate on the RHS.

I think this problem should be a natural generalization of the eigenproblem. Is there any theory studying it?

Comment: This might be extremely naive since I don't have almost any experience in operator theory, but if your operator is linear, can you not just decompose $f$ into $u+iv$,  solve the eigenproblems $$ \hat L u = \lambda u \quad\text{and}\quad \hat L v = -\lambda v, $$ and then intersect the solution spaces?

Comment: @Sobi Thanks for your comment. The operator $\hat{L}$ in the problem I encountered, is linear but not real in general.

Comment: Oh, I see! Good luck with finding a solution! =)

Comment: If $Lf=λ\bar f$ then also $\bar L \bar f =\barλ f$ and thus $\bar L L f=|λ|^2 f$ which should allow to determine the eigenfunctions of the fourth order operator which then have to be reduced to the solutions of the equation.

Comment: @WeinEld Typo in the title?